# UC SSL Certificate hyperlink problems

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, opencart

I've installed a UC Multi-Domain SSL Certificate from Entrust for use with two OpenCart installs and a corporate domain all hosted at the same IP.

I have 3 domains on the certificate in the following order

- www.example.com
- www.example2.com
- www.example2.ca

when I activate SSL in OpenCart and the config.php my links to secure areas are changed; however, strange things are happening to these links.

Example:

```
 Page: www.example2.com
 Link: https://www.example2.com/admin
 Resulting Page: https://www.example.com/admin
 OR https://www.example2.com/admin (but code from https://www.example.com/admin)
 OR if https://https://www.example.com/admin doesn't exist I get a 404 page
```

www.example.com/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
```

www.example2.com/.htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
```

www.example2.com/php.ini

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 64M;
max_execution_time = 18000;
upload_max_filesize = 999M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 20;
session.use_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 12000000;
allow_url_fopen = on;
```

www.example2.com/config.php

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.example2.com/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://www.example2.com/image/');
define('HTTP_ADMIN', 'http://www.example2.com/admin/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.example2.com/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://www.example2.com/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/user/example2.com/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/user/example2.com/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/user/example2.com/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/user/example2.com/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/user/example2.com/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/user/example2.com/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/user/example2.com/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/user/example2.com/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/user/example2.com/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/user/example2.com/system/logs/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
define('DB_PREFIX', '');
?>
```

www.example2.com/admin/config.php

```
<?php
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://www.example2.com/admin/');
define('HTTP_CATALOG', 'http://www.example2.com/');
define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://www.example2.com/image/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://www.example2.com/admin/');
define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'https://www.example2.com/image/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/home/user/example2.com/admin/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/home/user/example2.com/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '/home/user/example2.com/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/home/user/example2.com/admin/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/home/user/example2.com/admin/view/template/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/home/user/example2.com/system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/home/user/example2.com/image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/home/user/example2.com/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/home/user/example2.com/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/home/user/example2.com/system/logs/');
define('DIR_CATALOG', '/home/user/example2.com/catalog/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysql');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'username');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'database');
define('DB_PREFIX', '');
?>
```

Apache: 2.2.17

Any help would be great.

taylorjes

Comment: Rather off-topic for SO (more for ServerFault, you could flag it and ask a moderator to have it moved). It would be better to see how you've configured your `VirtualHosts`.

Comment: Yea, I'm not the host and unfortunatly they can't figure it out either... I'll request a move and see what happens

Comment: So after some explanation from my host and developers I've run aground... apparently a UC SSL only secures the original domain (www.example.com) and all secure traffic is direct there... now I'm going to try and mod_rewrite both sites as www.example.com/example2.com and www.example.com/example2.ca to keep the SSL happy

Comment: You could in principle configure the same certificate on multiple VirtualHosts sharing the same IP address but with different `ServerName` entries (one for each of your host names). Your host would need to configure that in their Apache config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry to hear you are having issues. I passed this along to the Entrust Support team to see if they could provide some help. After they looked at your post they passed along the following.  “This is an odd issue because the SSL certificate does not direct traffic in anyway, it  is the website that controls where the user goes after clicking on a hyper link. This would be an issue with the coding on the site, the configuration or the re-direct is setup wrong.” I hope this helps you.